# Application doesn't show live Ads Banner on emulator

Tags: android, admob, ads

I tried to add Admob to my application and show real/live ads on my android emulator, However it only shows Test banner only.

Here's the AdView xml

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="********************">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

And here's my code

```
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  AdView mAdView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR) 
        .build();
    mAdView .loadAd(adRequest);
```

you need to add your emulator as test device.

Comment: admob does not show live read ads on test devices. it's their policy. on real devices it will show properly. Don't worry about that.

Comment: There isn't anyway to hijack it? I've seen many posts showing live ads without even meaning to

Comment: personally I am not aware of any. But I do know, any sort of attempt & if they can detect it will surely lead to your admob account ban

Answer (score 1):

Try to check it out in real device. Add usually doesnt show in emulator